# How do I debug hook_mail_alter()?

Tags: 8, debugging, emails

I need to debug `$message` on [`hook_mail_alter(&$message)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/8.2.x). In **D7** it was pretty easy to `dpm()` on `hook_mail_alter()`. Now in **D8** `dpm()` doesn't print the nicest output anymore.

I'ld like to see the possible methods I can use. So I'ld like to use `kint()`/`ksm()` but this seems to break the functionality of my site. I get a WOSD without Watchdog catching anything.

Did anyone else come across this issue? Do you have some tips how I can use Kint on `hook_mail_alter()` to print me useful output?

Comment: You did install the devel module, didn't you?

Comment: @alexej_d Yes of course, how else could I have used `dpm()`?

Comment: Just asked to be sure. Did you activate debug mode in your site settings? Can you check the error_log?

Comment: @alexej_d The way you asking, does this mean you get output when using `ksm()` on `hook_mail_alter()`?

Comment: I believe you should get output, but only if cache is off and wiped

Comment: You're probably sending a mail that has a user, node or other entity object as context and dpm() is dying trying to display it. I really recommend setting up a proper IDE (e.g. PhpStorm, not free but worth it) with xdebug integration. Working with a proper debugger will quickly save you hours and days of time.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir, PHPStorm is my main IDE. Maybe I finally should set up Xdebug!

Comment: If you already have PHPStorm, then yes, definitely.